# C# - Reserve disc memory(storage)for app

Tags: c#, .net, storage

I'm making an app that needs 500 MB of free disc space to run. How to make sure that that kind of disk space is always reserved for my app (even when app is turned of).

EOG

Comment: Why don't just warn the user if he doesn't have enough disk space at launch ?

Comment: What's the name of your app? I just want to make sure I never accidentally install it. ;)

Comment: This is already taken care of by Windows.  It starts to get loud with the user when disk space runs low.  The trigger was 500 MB for XP, nice coincidence.  Not sure what it is for Vista and up, disk space grows faster than my ability to fill it.  So, don't bother, running out of disk space is no different from running out of memory.  The kaboom is expected by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a 500MB "empty" file and minimize the size of the file when you need diskspace?

Answer (score 2):

When you install you application you can create a 500 MB file and use that whenever your application is running. However, it seems somewhat wasteful.

Another option is to let your application fail gracefully if it cannot create the files it need. Then you wouldn't have to reserve space and no space would be wasted when your application isn't running.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, your best option is to create a file of the size that you need. I'd like to add to this: depending on your task you can use this size as a virtual disk for storing your data (the one you need to be stored on the real disk). The benefit is that the data in container can be persistent and that you don't need to resize the file to free space for your needs - you just use the file itself.